# How control C# XAML slider value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is the XAML slider code:

```
<Slider x:Name="volumeSlider" VerticalAlignment="Center" ValueChanged="ChangeMediaVolume" 
    Height="23" Width="265" Margin="5" Maximum="1" Minimum="0"
                Value="0.1"  />
```

C# code:

```
public void ChangeMediaVolume(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> args)
{
    MyVideo.Volume = (double)volumeSlider.Value;
}
```

I want to add a condition which can control slider value. After that slider value separate 5 step, that value is changed According to some variable.

How to get this result?

Comment: What condition you are talking about? Add more details to the question.

Comment: I want to add condition which can control slider's value position                                                                         for example,  variable z is 0<z<1  ->  value = 0.1  ,  1<z<2  ->  value  = 0.2 ,  2<z<3 ->  value  = 0.3

Answer (score 0):

You simply need the to bind the value from the slider to the media.volume or the other way around - like you want!
Take a look at here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx

Comment: Or do you want this: volumeSlider.Value = MyVideo.Volume; but you should call this method maybe after the change of the media volume is completed.